# Linux ARM64 calling convention: What registers need saving by callee?

Tags: linux, arm64, calling-convention, abi

Is there a list of registers that, on aarch64 Linux/BSD, the callee absolutely must save/restore if the callee is going to use them? The ABI documentation seemed muddled on this point. Or at least, it's nowhere as clear as the ABI documentation for other ISAs.

I'm asking for a list of specific 64-bit registers that need to be saved *by the callee* if they are going to be modified by the callee.

Comment: Simple - that's what the application binary interface (ABI) for the chip tells you must be done. The concept is the same for all processors. When a function call is made, the ABI tells you "These values are not preserved after a function call, so the callee will need to stash them somewhere and then restore their values when done...". [13.2 Accessing Arguments in a Function](http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-arg-access.html) is a good read. (bottom of page most important)

Comment: That link is for aarch32, not aarch64.

Comment: See the part above *"The concept is the same for all processors"* You can find the same information specifying what registers are callee saved in the aarch64 ABI See [General-purpose Registers](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0055/d/) Table 2.

Comment: Updated link for Cortex-A Processors Aarch64 [Parameters in general-purpose registers](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/The-ABI-for-ARM-64-bit-Architecture/Register-use-in-the-AArch64-Procedure-Call-Standard/Parameters-in-general-purpose-registers)

Answer (score 3):

This is not part of the ISA specification because it has nothing to do with the ISA. OS vendors are free to implement any ABI they so desire.

Linux follows the [AAPCS64 ABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst), which mandates:

> A subroutine invocation must preserve the contents of the registers r19-r29 and SP. All 64 bits of each value stored in r19-r29 must be preserved, even when using the ILP32 data model [...].

And for SIMD/floating-point:

> Registers v8-v15 must be preserved by a callee across subroutine calls; [...]. Additionally, only the bottom 64 bits of each value stored in v8-v15 need to be preserved; it is the responsibility of the caller to preserve larger values.

Comment: I didn't say it has anything to do with the ISA. You should read the post before responding to it.